# How do I avoid specifying the defaulAuthor element during javadoc creation

Tags: java, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

How do I avoid specifying the defaulAuthor element during javadoc creation using the javadoc [plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/fix-mojo.html). I don't want the author element, since the javadocs will be shipped to customers.

Answer (score 0):

How about specifying a generic author (i.e. your company)?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set it to be the name of your company in a parent pom?  See [plugin configuration options](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/fix-mojo.html#defaultAuthor)

Comment: Maybe I can do that, but I have never seen author information in some of the commonly used java libraries

Comment: I normally write my own javadoc, I'm not convinced that something generating it for me (other than my IDE when I actually want it) is useful.  Consider that if you are adding javadoc without actually writing any documentation what value you are adding?

Comment: I am just creating the javadoc skeleton by running the fix command. Our whole intention is to fill it with documentation, this is just a pre-requisite for us

Comment: The question was primarily related to avoid specifying the author information